# Science Fiction version of Queneau's "Exercices de Style"?

Tags: identification-request, french-language

I somewhere read there is an "extended" version (I only know the "standard" one which has a German translation) of Queneau's "Exercices de Style". Including an SF version (which interests me most). Unfortunately, I couldn't dig up any further information. Anyone having bibliographic info (or even a link)?

Comment: Do you mean "Exercices de SFstyle"? It's "inspired" by Queneau, but was written by George Pierru.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez: Too long ago that I recall it - this then would explain why I can google zilch. THX for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Exercices de Style](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exercices_de_style)*  is an unusual work by the French writer Raymond Queneau. Published in 1947, it tells the same short anecdote in 99 different ways. In the anecdote the narrator meets a young man with a long neck on a bus, wearing a soft hat decorated with a braid instead of a ribbon. The young man argues with another traveler, then goes to sit down. A little later, the narrator meets the same young man deep in conversation with a friend who advises him to adjust a button on his overcoat.

The 99 styles cover many different ways of describing these events, but a science fictional interpretation is not one of them. In 1984 George Pierru, inspired by Queneau's work, wrote *[Exercices de SFtyle](https://www.quarante-deux.org/recits/pierru/pastiches/exercices.html)* which remedied this omission; the first begins:

> One day, around 12 UT, on the side of the Sheckley Monad, on the
> particularly crowded high-speed moving sidewalk, I saw a homoid with a
> very slender neck who wore a cape decorated with a plastic braid
> instead of ribbon.

It is interesting that the OP mentions the German translation of the exercises, *Stilübungen*. The first translation was made in 1961 by Eugen Helmlé and Ludwig Harig, and contained just the original 99 exercises. A more recent translation from 2016 by by Frank Heibert and Hinrich Schmidt-Henkel contains 122 exercises. I have not read it, but according to a [review on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Stil%C3%BCbungen/product-reviews/3518224956/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews), one of the stories begins "In einer fliegenden Untertasse der Linie Alpha Kassiopeia..." ("In a flying saucer of the Alpha Cassiopeia line..."), which would seem to indicate some science fiction content in at least some of the additional stories.

Additional note: The version quoted above was an Exercise "published outside *Exercices de Style*" in *Arts* November 1954. It is entitled "Science Fiction", and begins:

> On a flying saucer found on Cassiopeia’s Alpha Line (via Betelgeuse
> and Aldebaran), I noticed, among my travelling companions, a young
> Martian whose too-long neck and plaited head prodigiously irritated
> me.